# Cannot find name 'FontFace'. TS2304

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-face

I am trying to load fonts dynamically for my project. I dont understand why I'm getting this error.

**"Cannot find name 'FontFace'.  TS2304"**

Following is the code for your reference:

```
 const loadFont = (name: string, source: string) => {
    const font = new FontFace(name, `url(${source})`);
    font
      .load()
      .then(function (loadedFont: any) {
        document.fonts.add(loadedFont);
        document.body.style.fontFamily = name;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Are you using Typescript? Have you installed related type definition file?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace This is not a lib m using, this is a default object.  Like MediaStream, Video, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Typescript, make sure you have installed type definitions for CSS Font loading modules

```
npm install --save @types/css-font-loading-module
```

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/css-font-loading-module

Answer (score 0):

after installing also you should add type to tsconfig.json, otherwise it will not work.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* other compiler options... */
    "types": ["css-font-loading-module"]
  }
}
```